# How can I transform a scalar function in another subspace?

Tags: functions, metric-spaces

I hope this question is not too silly, but I can not remember any practical solution to this. So, if I have a scalar function (distance $d(x,x')$) which is defined on an ensemble $X$ and I transform this space into another space $Y$ with fewer dimensions (e.g. projection with/without conditions on preserving the distance space), can I define a new distance function on the new subspace which approximates the first distance function?

Comment: A subspace is also a subset, in your case $Y\subseteq X$. If $d$ is defined on $X\times X$, it is also defined on $Y\times Y$. So you can use the same distance function.

Comment: Sorry I expressed badly the question. Y is a transformation of X (e.g. projection). Maybe you are right but I do not know it is valid also for more general conditions (e.g. no distance space preservation) and I am sure that this reduction of the space would have to deal with the crowding problem. I tried to describe this better in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p:X\to Y$ be a projection from $X$ to $Y$ and $p^{-1}(y):=\{x\mid p(x)=y\}$. Then you can define a metric $\tilde d$ by $$\tilde d(y_1,y_2):=\min_{x_1\in p^{-1}(y_1),\\x_2\in p^{-1}(y_2)}d(x_1,x_2)$$

Comment: So this is generally true if considered $p^{-1}$ as an injective function. This is certainly correct but I was trying to find a way to avoid the retransformation of $y_1$, $y_2$ to $x_1,x_2$ meaning that I would like to have a new space of 'projected' distances which are somehow a composition of $p^{-1}$ and $d$ (if it is possible).